# VBA code that counts excludes holidays and weekends between start date and end date

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I used the code below to count the actual working days excluding weekends. On access database there is a table for holidays and the code is written in a way to exclude a day from the count if its a holiday. When I run the code, I receive the error 2950 : Reserved error.

I have no experience with linking access to excel but I enabled from tool> references MS access 14.0 object library

---

```
Public Function WorkingDays(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Integer
'-- Return the number of WorkingDays between StartDate and EndDate
Error GoTo err_workingDays

Dim intCount As Integer

If IsDate(StartDate) And IsDate(EndDate) Then
 If EndDate >= StartDate Then

  intCount = 0
  Do While StartDate < EndDate
     StartDate = StartDate + 1

      If Weekday(StartDate, vbMonday) <= 5 And IsNull(DLookup("[Holiday]", "tblHolidays", _
        "[HolDate] = " & Format(StartDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#;;;\N\u\l\l"))) Then

        intCount = intCount + 1

     End If
  Loop
  WorkingDays = intCount + 1
   Else
      WorkingDays = -1  
   End If
Else
   WorkingDays = -1  
End If

 exit_workingDays:
   Exit Function

err_workingDays:
   MsgBox "Error No:    " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
   "Description: " & Err.Description
   Resume exit_workingDays

End Function
```

Comment: What's wrong with NetWorkDays_Intl ?

Comment: Are you executing this from Excel? If so, `DLookUp` is not going to work.

Comment: 1 You need to link to the "Microsoft Active X Data Objects" library, not the Access library.  2 You would then have to write a function that executes a SQL query on your table to return the data you want, after initiating a data connection. I would google networkdays as a simpler solution, as Jeeped said.

Comment: But whats wrong with the Dlookup? I dont know how to write a SQL query in additoin i just need to know if the word "holiday" is written next to the date so that i can exclude it from the count. I don't want to retrieve anything.

Comment: Well.... `DLookUp` is executed against the currently open Access database. If you execute that from Excel, there's no open Access database, thus it fails.

Comment: Your simplest solution is to import the holiday table from access into a worksheet behind your current sheet using Data Query and then use a VLOOKUP against that retrieved table. You could use VBA to update the retrieved table everytime you opened your workbook.

Comment: @Jeeped Networkdays_intl works fine and everything, but this function is a part of plan scheduler tool so the employees will post their holidays and it will be recorded on access

Comment: @erik von asmuth the access table is open. But either ways it doesnt work. I get the same error on the Dlookup function.

Comment: Yes, of course, because it's not open in _Excel_. Like I said, not going to work.

Comment: @harassed dad i can insert the date from access to excel from the insert ribbon but the updates are not reflected automatically between excel and Access. How can I use the data query as you have mentioned?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I got what you mean. i thought you were talking about the database not the function

Comment: @HarassedDad The code has actually worked once Microsoft Active X data Objects has been enabled. thank you

Comment: @Harasseddad So what can I do if i want the excel value to be refreshed automatically once I a change has happened in the access holiday table

Answer (score 0):

You can add references to Access and DAO:

- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library

Then include this code in your workbook:

```
Public Function IsLookupDate(ByVal SomeDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsLookup    As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Filter      As String

    Set db = DAO.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("d:\path\holidays.accdb")
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblHolidays", dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.FindFirst "[Date] = #" & Format(SomeDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

    IsLookupDate = Not rs.NoMatch

End Function
```

Then, to check for a holiday:

```
IsHoliday = NameOfYourWorkbook.IsLookupDate(StartDate)
```

Of course, speed this up by integrating it into your loop.